# SSH and open file for editing in same command

Tags: ssh, vim

I have a command in a server that I edit with frequency. I have two do it in two steps: `ssh` to the server and `vim` the file. I’d like to do this in a single step, so I can `alias` it in my local shell. If I

```
ssh myserver vim /path/to/file
```

I get

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Because `ssh` is expecting to just run the command and return the output. But what I need is for `ssh` to open the connection, *stay there*, execute the command and wait.

Is that possible, without having to do anything on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ssh -t myserver vim /path/to/file
```

> `-t`
>   Force pseudo-terminal allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple `-t` options force tty allocation, even if `ssh` has no local tty.

<sup>([source](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#t))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of things here. I am assuming that the edit *must* be a manual edit, i.e. no *ed* or *sed* commands.
1. Make sure your local machine has your *xhost* configured to allow a display from another node.
`xhost +` just to test, if you are unsure.
2. use  `ssh -X myserver vim /path/to/file`
3. you may need to specify  the *-n* or *-t* option on the ssh command.
4. do you have *gvim* installed? It can create an X11 window.
5. You may have to execute the terminal window command, and have it execute vim.

I've done this type of thing several times. I lot of it depends on your OS versions.

Comment: I neither have X (macOS local machine, headless server) nor do I want a GUI. The `-t` answer is what I was looking for.